# Solr Group using child attribute

Tags: solr, information-retrieval

I have a collection of documents whose structure is as follows:

```
    {
        "title": "Shearer: Trossard tore Fulham apart",
        "summary": "Premier League's record goalscorer hails Arsenal star following his hat-trick of assists",
        "text": "\n A virtuoso performance from  Leandro Trossard  inspired  Arsenal 's emphatic victory at  Fulham , with the Belgian producing a hat-trick of assists in a  3-0 win  for the Premier League leaders. \n He set up  Gabriel  for the opening goal from a corner, before then producing crosses for  Gabriel Martinelli  and  Martin Odegaard  as the Gunners retained their five-point lead over  Manchester City  at the top of the table. \n In becoming the first ever player to set up three goals in the first half of an away match, Trossard earned a place in the Team of the Week chosen by the Premier League's all-time top scorer  Alan Shearer . \n \n \n \ud83c\udf1f  @alanshearer 's Team of the Week has landed \ud83d\udeec What do you make of his picks? \ud83d\udc47  pic.twitter.com/qPqfpiFnU3 \n\u2014 Premier League (@premierleague)  March 13, 2023 \n \n Gavin Bazunu (Southampton) \"His incredible stop from  Bruno Fernandes  was one of two big saves that helped  Southampton  earn a  crucial point .\"\u00a0 \n Kyle Walker-Peters (Southampton) \" Manchester United  struggled to handle his attacking play and he was very unfortunate not to have found a winner for Saints.\"\u00a0 \n James Tarkowski (Everton) \"He dealt with  Ivan Toney  very well - not many defenders can say that - to help  Everton  to a vital  1-0 win .\" \n Gabriel (Arsenal) \"He loves a goal against Fulham doesn't he? That's now three goals against them.\" \n Ben Chilwell (Chelsea) \"His volley for the opener showed excellent technique as  Chelsea 's upturn in form continued.\" \n Dango Ouattara (AFC Bournemouth) \"He showed brilliant skill and composure to set up  Philip Billing  in the  1-0 win against Liverpool , before working hard to help  Bournemouth  defend that lead.\" \n Rodri (Man City) \"His passing kept Man City on the front foot against  Crystal Palace  as he was rightly  lauded by his manager Pep Guardiola .\" \n Martin Odegaard (Arsenal) \"The Arsenal captain had the Fulham defence on strings for the third goal.\" \n Leandro Trossard (Arsenal) \"The Belgian tore Fulham apart and was a constant threat throughout. He will have a big part to play in the title run-in.\" \n Alexander Isak (Newcastle) \"What a brilliant header from the big man! And what a huge goal for  Newcastle United .\" \n Harry Kane (Spurs) \"The  Tottenham Hotspur  striker showed his class once again as he moved on to 20 Premier League goals for the season.\" \n Manager:  Gary O'Neil (AFC Bournemouth) \"His plan worked to perfection against  Liverpool  as they created very little against his side. What a superb display from his team.\" \n",
        "date": "2023-03-13T00:00:00Z",
        "url": "https://www.premierleague.com/news/3109050",
        "named_game": {},
        "named_teams": [
            {
                "name": "FC Fulham",
                "abbreviation": "FUL"
            }
        ],
        "named_players": []
    },
```

I want to get the articles about comebacks, grouped by the teams named in the article, which is a field of the named_teams nested documents.
I am using the following query

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:8983/solr/articles/query?group=true%3Dtrue&group.field=abbreviation&group.limit=10&parent.q={!parent%20which="*:*%20-_nest_path_:*"%20v=\{!terms%20f=id%20v=$row.id\}}&fl=*,parent:\[subquery\]' -d '
{
    "query": "_nest_path_:\\/named_teams AND ({!child of=\"*:* -_nest_path_:*\"}title:comeback OR summary:comeback OR text:comeback)"
}'
```

But really the most important part is

```
parent.q={!parent%20which="*:*%20-_nest_path_:*"%20v=\{!terms%20f=id%20v=$row.id\}}
```

I want to use the sub query to get the parent of the matched document. This should work since the term query matches the team document that was already matched, and the parent query should match it's parent, getting the wanted articles for that team.

However, I'm getting

```
{
                                                                                        "groupValue":"mci",
                                                                                        "doclist":{
                                                                                          "numFound":5,
                                                                                          "start":0,
                                                                                          "numFoundExact":true,
                                                                                          "docs":[{
                                                                                            "name":"Manchester City FC",
                                                                                            "abbreviation":"MCI",
                                                                                            "id":"b57a69cc-55fd-43fe-be42-7a27542401e9/named_teams#",
                                                                                            "_version_":1782282614877454336,
                                                                                            "parent":{
                                                                                              "numFound":1,
                                                                                              "start":0,
                                                                                              "numFoundExact":true,
                                                                                              "docs":[{
                                                                                                "name":"Manchester City FC",
                                                                                                "abbreviation":"MCI",
                                                                                                "id":"b57a69cc-55fd-43fe-be42-7a27542401e9/named_teams#",
                                                                                                "_version_":1782282614877454336
                                                                                              }]
                                                                                            }
                                                                                          },{
                                                                                            "name":"Manchester City FC",
                                                                                            "abbreviation":"MCI",
                                                                                            "id":"eb2ed808-c55c-43a1-8d10-25165d932e19/named_teams#",
                                                                                            "_version_":1782282615101849603,
                                                                                            "parent":{
                                                                                              "numFound":1,
                                                                                              "start":0,
                                                                                              "numFoundExact":true,
                                                                                              "docs":[{
                                                                                                "name":"Manchester City FC",
                                                                                                "abbreviation":"MCI",
                                                                                                "id":"eb2ed808-c55c-43a1-8d10-25165d932e19/named_teams#",
                                                                                                "_version_":1782282615101849603
                                                                                              }]
                                                                                            }
                                                                                          },{
                                                                                            "name":"Manchester City FC",
                                                                                            "abbreviation":"MCI",
                                                                                            "id":"27a963ab-1909-4f29-8dce-5989347c5bf2/named_teams#",
                                                                                            "_version_":1782282615524425729,
                                                                                            "parent":{
                                                                                              "numFound":1,
                                                                                              "start":0,
                                                                                              "numFoundExact":true,
                                                                                              "docs":[{
                                                                                                "name":"Manchester City FC",
                                                                                                "abbreviation":"MCI",
                                                                                                "id":"27a963ab-1909-4f29-8dce-5989347c5bf2/named_teams#",
                                                                                                "_version_":1782282615524425729
                                                                                              }]
                                                                                            }
                                                                                          },{
                                                                                            "name":"Manchester City FC",
                                                                                            "abbreviation":"MCI",
                                                                                            "id":"8834cdb6-3ddf-44e8-96da-a71478b1fe6d/named_teams#",
                                                                                            "_version_":1782282612319977473,
                                                                                            "parent":{
                                                                                              "numFound":1,
                                                                                              "start":0,
                                                                                              "numFoundExact":true,
                                                                                              "docs":[{
                                                                                                "name":"Manchester City FC",
                                                                                                "abbreviation":"MCI",
                                                                                                "id":"8834cdb6-3ddf-44e8-96da-a71478b1fe6d/named_teams#",
                                                                                                "_version_":1782282612319977473
                                                                                              }]
                                                                                            }
                                                                                          },{
                                                                                            "name":"Manchester City FC",
                                                                                            "abbreviation":"MCI",
                                                                                            "id":"887474ab-bcad-44d9-8738-f60169a51042/named_teams#1",
                                                                                            "_version_":1782282612553809922,
                                                                                            "parent":{
                                                                                              "numFound":1,
                                                                                              "start":0,
                                                                                              "numFoundExact":true,
                                                                                              "docs":[{
                                                                                                "name":"Manchester City FC",
                                                                                                "abbreviation":"MCI",
                                                                                                "id":"887474ab-bcad-44d9-8738-f60169a51042/named_teams#1",
                                                                                                "_version_":1782282612553809922
                                                                                              }]
                                                                                            }
                                                                                          }]
                                                                                        }
                                                                                      }]
                                                                                    }
```

Meaning the subquery is matching the team itself rather than it's parent.
What am I doing wrong?